# Get Value of child in ListWheelScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get the value of the child text widget, or even if there is a way to get the value from the List that I populate the Text widgets from. when you scroll and the wheel stops, I would like to extract the value of the selectedItem.

As I use infinite scroll I cannot map the value of the selectedItem to the List

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  FixedExtentScrollController fixedExtentScrollController =
      new FixedExtentScrollController();

// I would like to get one of these values
  List<String> numbers = [
    'one',
    'two',
    'three',
    'four',
    'five',
    'six',
    'seven',
    'eight',
    'nine'
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      color: Colors.white,
      home: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 800.0,
          width: 250.0,
          child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
            itemExtent: 100,
            controller: fixedExtentScrollController,
            physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
            onSelectedItemChanged: (_) {
              print(fixedExtentScrollController.selectedItem.);
            },
            childDelegate: ListWheelChildLoopingListDelegate(
              children: <Widget>[
                ...numbers.map((String number) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 100.0,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text( 
                        number,  //Here is the child value I would like to get
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 24.0,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                            decoration: TextDecoration.none),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                })
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListWheelScrollView-class.html), you could use onSelectedItemChanged

> onSelectedItemChanged → ValueChanged
>       On optional listener that's called when the centered item changes.

The value you are looking for can be found changing your code to:

```
onSelectedItemChanged: (i) {
    print(numbers[i]);
},
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Francisco, the issue is I have infinite scroll so the value cannot be mapped, infinite scroll gives both infinite negative and positive values. So if I keep scrolling down the value will keep going up and it would be bigger than my list. 

If I remove infinite scroll I can do your suggestion but then I don't achieve the UX I wanted.

Comment: Never mind, I see what you done there, you just solved my issue, I was not passing in 'I', you are a legend

Comment: You are welcome. I am sorry I were not clear about passing i, I will keep it in mind for the future.